# Kafka log process flow

Tags: logging, stream, apache-kafka

I need to copy or bring logs from a remote server (S1) to another server (S2) on a real-time basis via Kafka. Should Kafka be installed on both the machines to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Kafka would run in a dedicated cluster and you connect both your servers to Kafka. The best way would be to use Kafka Connect. But you can of course also implement a producer client on the first server and a consumer client on the second.

- http://kafka.apache.org/documentation#connect
- http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html